# Why does Tagore not consistently use ‘thou’ when addressing the supreme being in Gitanjali?

Tags: poetry, style, rabindranath-tagore, bengali-language, gitanjali

The large majority of poems in the English version of Tagore's *Gitanjali* address a supreme being. Tagore uses the pronouns "thou", "thee" and "thy" in almost all of these 103 poems. However, a few use "you", for example [49: You came down from your throne and stood at my cottage door](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gitanjali/49).

Some of the poems that use "you" appear to have a different addressee, e.g. [45](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gitanjali/45) and [62](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gitanjali/62), where the addressee seems to be a normal human being. However, poem 49 is not addressed at an ordinary human being but at the same supreme being that is addressed in most of the poems. Does this reflect a variation in pronouns in the Bengali texts that Tagore translated. (Some of these were not from the Bengali *Gitanjali*.) Or does it have a different reason that I have failed to notice?